# Split UTF8 using Preg_Split

Tags: php, regex

I have an Arabic paragraph which need to be split in half.

The delimiter is:

معلومات هامة

My attempt:

```
$st = utf8_encode("معلومات هامة");
$info = preg_split('/'.$st.'/', $paragraph);
```

It didn't help, I get array with element 0 which hold the whole paragraph, so
info output is exactly as paragraph output.

Note: the paragraph has inconsistent newlines and spaces.

Comment: Try adding the unicode modifier to the end of your regex (like `/regex/u`).

Comment: '/معلومات هامة/smu'  ........ didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with [`mb_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php) to handle UTF-8 content.

Also you can try to prepend this function with:

```
mb_internal_encoding( 'UTF-8'); 
mb_regex_encoding( 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Didn't help..........
 mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8'); 
 mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
 $imp = mb_split('/معلومات هامة/sm', $detailedDesc_[11]);

Comment: @user311509: remove the slashes around the first argument to `mb_split`.